# Не загружаются изображения в библиотеке pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Вот часть кода:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,480))

pygame.display.set_caption("First game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

[image: это сама ошибка]

[image: все файлы находятся в одной папке]

Почему он не видит вообще эти картинки?

Comment: Каким образом запускаете скрипт? Сделайте `import sys` в начале и после импортов `print(sys.path)`. Напечатанный путь совпадает с тем, что в файловом менеджере?

Comment: @Андрей а как это посмотреть ?

Comment: Что именно? Путь в файловом менеджере находится в строке над файлами, по `F6` можно выделить

Comment: @Андрей >Каким образом запускаете скрипт? просто нажимаю на файл с кодом   >Сделайте import sys в начале и после импортов print(sys.path). Напечатанный путь совпадает с тем, что в файловом менеджере? не очень понимаю что надо сделать и зачем import sys

Comment: То, что выдаёт `print(sys.path)`, совпадает с содержимым строки в файловом менеджере?

Comment: @Андрей print(sys.path) а куда это надо вводить

Comment: После импортов, как упоминалось выше

Comment: @Андрей а как я посмотрю что он мне напишет если он сразу вылетает

Comment: Сделайте задержку с помощью `input()` или `sleep()`, например

Comment: @Андрей да путь и вправду не совпадает...

Comment: Можете ввести `cmd` (только это слово, ничего больше) вместо пути в файловом менеджере, откроется консоль в этой папке. В ней набираете `python <имя_скрипта>.py` или `python3 <имя_скрипта>.py`, должно сработать

Comment: Не думаю, что переустановка поможет. Просто запускайте из консоли. А какой путь при запуске по щелчку выдаёт?

Comment: @Андрей Спасибо большое! что все разжевали и помогли